# Refresh Page for interval using js

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

How can i refresh a page for every one minute using javascript.
Note: I don't have control/option to edit HTML body tag (where we usually call onload function).

Comment: i hope this is a read-only type of page, otherwise users may get pretty annoyed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just insert this code anywhere in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    location = ''
  },60000)
</script>
```

Comment: What if I want to only have this work on a specific URL.  I ask I want to use this on a MediaWiki site for myself on Special:MyPage/common.js to only refresh when I'm sitting on Special:Watchlist waiting for a response.

Comment: Maybe you could do something like `if (location == 'your url') { setTimeout(...,60000) }`

Comment: Could you please expand on why this code performs the reload of the full page?

Comment: 'setTimeout' function call only once right ? then How do I update the screen with an interval with a time0ut.

Answer (score 24):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 60 * 1000);
</script>
```

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) will [reload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) the page after a specified number of milliseconds, hence `60 * 1000 = 1m`. Also, since the page is being refreshed, the timeout will always be set on page load.

Comment: Should change that to `setTimeout`. And tell him to put that in the code for the page, not in the console or something.

Answer (score 12):

You do not need to have the code in the body tag. Just add this snippet below and it should work no matter where it is in the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval('window.location.reload()', 60000);
</script>
```

As long as you can access the HTML some where and your editor doesn't filter out  tags you should be fine. If your editor has a separate area for JavaScript code then just enter setInterval line. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the thing mate!
*(Point 4 is for this particular question)*

1). If you want to reload the same windows over and over again then just execute
`window.location.reload()`

2).  If you want to hard reload from the server then execute
`window.location.reload(true)` 
(basically, just pass `true` as a boolean arg to the same line of code)

3). If you want to do the same job as point 1 and 2 with a time out. i.e. execute the reload after some time JUST ONCE, then execute
`setTimeout("window.location.reload()",10000);`
(this should execute on the window after 10 sec. JUST ONCE)

4). If you want to keep reloading the window with a certain timeout then execute
`setInterval("window.location.reload()",10000);`

(this should execute on the window after 10 sec. with 10 sec. for the interval)

Surely,there're many ways to pass a callback.. 
`setInterval(function(){window.location.reload();},10000);`
or

```
<code>
function call1(){
  location.reload(true);
}
setInterval(call1,10000);
</code>
```

*Note:*
-Have a look at MDN Guides for [setTimeout][1] and [setInterval][2] functions.
-Using the `window` object is optional but good to be used. (window is a global object and already available to your current window.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to edit the page, here's the trick. Open the console and write the below-mentioned snippet.

```
INTERVAL = 5    // seconds
STOP_AFTER = 15 // seconds

// Open the same link in the new tab
win1 = window.open(location.href);

// At every 5 seconds, reload the page
timer1 = setInterval(() => {
    win1.location.reload();
    console.log("Refreshed");
},INTERVAL*1000)

// Stop reloading after 15 seconds
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(timer1), STOP_AFTER*1000)
```

1. Since you want to reload it, you can not simply write location.reload() since the console will be cleared once it is reloaded.
2. Therefore, it will open a new tab with the same link. It will be easily able to control the 2nd tab using the console of the 1st tab.

Answer (score -1):

When your URL has parameters, it seems that using `location = ''` doesn't work in IE8. The page reloads without any parameters.

The following code works for me :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
  },10000)
</script>
```