# Automatic page refresh using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest

I have an HTML page that should reload itself every 60 seconds. The easiest way to do that would be to use this meta tag in the head of the HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
```

but unfortunately I just can't use it. Indeed the HTML page will be loaded on an iPad running [Panic's Status Board](http://panic.com/statusboard/), and the user manual says:

> If your webpage shows data that updates frequently, we recommend using XMLHttpRequest to fetch and replace content dynamically. Do not use meta-refresh; Status Board’s CSS will not be injected into a page that is refreshed this way.

So how could I make the HTML page reload itself each 60 seconds using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: why don't you use JS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038183/refresh-page-for-interval-using-js

Answer (score 0):

As @Athul AK suggested, I used JavaScript, which solved the problem.