# Does session_destroy() work without page refresh?

Tags: php, session

What I want is to be able to delete session data without page refresh.
So let's say my user created a session and left his computer on sleep mode for two years, I want to delete his session after 4800s...
How can I do that?

At the moment, I have a code which only deletеs session on refresh only.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 4800)) {
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();  // destroy session data in storage
}

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Or does this code work without page refresh?
If not, how can constantly update this code?

Comment: If they make another request to the server, Then your code will run and eventually destroy the session.

Comment: I think JavaScript is a better fit for this, as it operates on the client side, not the server side.

Comment: The code won't update itself unless you tell it to. Add a listener to it that refreshes every time interval you need.

Comment: *"So lets say my user created a session and left his computer on sleep mode for two years"* - There's bound to be a power failure and that person's going to have to eventually recharge their batteries. Who leaves a computer on for 2 years?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I will go with javascript 'setTimeout' function... 
I knew that I can use it, but just wanted to make sure there's nothing else out there.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code anywhere in your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    location = ''
  },60000)
</script>
```

reference: [Refresh Page for interval using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038183/refresh-page-for-interval-using-js)

Answer (score -1):

**100% Working Just Add This Code Once**

```
setTimeout(function () {
window.location.href = "";
}, 3000);
```