# How to make a HTML Frame Update itself Every X seconds without Meta or Header?

Tags: html, refresh, frame, meta

I am trying to include a Teamspeak Viewer on my Website. My plan until now is to split the Site in two pieces with two frames. The Code i use right now:

```
<frameset cols="85%,15%">
    <frame name="content" src="the_real_page.html" /> <-- its not called like that...
    <frame name="tsviewer" src="thetsviewer.php" />
</frameset>
```

followed by the noframe part.

Now, i try to make the tsviewer Frame Autoupdate every 10 Seconds, so that the clients listed are more or less up-to-date with the server itself. Meta Element does not work nor does the refresh header, as many browsers block autorefreshing on webpages and don't even notify the user when they block a frame update...

Any other idea how to make the website query itself again or make the browser query the frame again?

Sincerely

ComicZockt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the javascript approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038183/refresh-page-for-interval-using-js). Just insert this code anywhere in `thetsviewer.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    location = ''
  },10000)
</script>
```

Comment: So i think the 60000 is the refresh time in milliseconds?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I forgot to change that parameter to match your question.  Now fixed.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for that approach, the frame now reloads with the notification still appearing... But it keeps updating, so Success!