# Auto Refresh page specific

Tags: javascript, html

How would i go about a AUTO refresh code in Java or HTML that refreshes every 3 hrs and 45 min?  Not like per user like even if its a user has been on the page only 10 min if its been 3 hours and 45 min since the last Refresh it will refresh anyway so like 3 hours and 45 min Server time not User time if that makes sense like 12:45 am 3:45 am 6:45 am 9:45 am 12:45 pm 3:45 Pm... Soo on soo on Hope this makes sense thanks for your help guys!

i have tried the following but it goes off user time

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="13500" >
```

Comment: I'd recommend setting up [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or [server-sent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) events.

Comment: Im using shared hosting with cpanel i really need a javascript if i can

Comment: it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038183/refresh-page-for-interval-using-js

Comment: that goes by user time and not server time tho dont it? Like if the user has only been there 10 min it wont refresh  until they are on the page 3 hours and 35 more min. time i think

Comment: How flexible is the 3 hour, 45 minute requirement? If it were a 3-hour refresh period, you could check every minute if it was 12:00 AM/PM, 3:00 AM/PM, 6:00 AM/PM or 9:00 AM/PM. Or if it were a 4-hour refresh period, you could simply check every minute for 12:00 AM/PM, 4:00 AM/PM or 8:00 AM/PM

Comment: Have the server inject the proper timeout value and it'll be fine...

Comment: i got a token that expires every 4 hours but the token up dates at 3 hrs and 30 min so i need the page to refresh about 3 hrs 40- 3 hr 45 minish so its updated before the 4 hour mark and kills everything

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in plain JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
    //You can change this value based on the server location.
    var offset = -5;
    var now = new Date();
    var utc = now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var serverTime = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    var hours = serverTime.getHours();
    var minutes = serverTime.getMinutes();
    if((hours % 3 == 0) && (minutes % 45 == 0)){
        location.reload();
    }
}, 30000);
</script>
```

You can include this script in your page and it will reload every three hours. The setTimeout is set to call every 30000ms or every 30 seconds.

Edit:
Added offset value for handling multiple server time zones. 
You can refer to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) for exact values.

Thanks @ChrisForrence for the suggestion.

Comment: @Raghuram Kasyap after testing this dont work.. your code for every 3 hours only works  for certain people thats actually in the -5 timezone everyone else dont get refreshed

Comment: I see that you cannot use chat rooms. I've uploaded a working [sample on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKQeGP?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will refresh the webpage based on the server time.

To fix the issue you need to use a timer and add function using javascript and based on it you can start the timer when you access the page and after every regular interval, you can refresh.

Use this URl for sample code snippet : http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/autofresh.shtml

```
var limit="****" // time like "225:00" minutes
    function beginrefresh(){
        if (parselimit==1)
            window.location.reload()
        else{ 
            parselimit-=1
            curmin=Math.floor(parselimit/60)
            cursec=parselimit%60
            if (curmin!=0)
                curtime=curmin+" minutes and "+cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
            else
                curtime=cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
            document.title = doctitle + ' (' + curtime +')'
            setTimeout("beginrefresh()",1000)
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please comment before downvoting. This is clearly a legit answer to the issue.

Comment: Well, it looks like the asker wants the page to refresh for all users at the same time. This code will refresh at a different time for each user.

Comment: Yes i am wanting it to refresh for all users at the same time