# Reload page after 2 seconds using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm reloading the page like this `window.location.reload();` is there a way to have it do the same thing but after 2 seconds?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh Page for interval using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038183/refresh-page-for-interval-using-js)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` functions available in Javascript.

 Refer to the SO question for its working. - [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)